# Googe Maps: Do I have to use Ionic Native?

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

I have just upgraded from `Ionic 2 beta` to `rc3`.  In order to eliminate compilation errors I changed my Google Maps implementation to use the [Ionic native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/) api.  This fixed my compilation errors, but I see that the [Ionic native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/) api has limitations. For example, there is no `fitBounds` function that is in googles api.

**Question**

Is it possible to use `Ionic 2 rc3` with using Googles api directly and not the [Ionic native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/) api?

If so, How should I configure my app to use the api?

Or, is there any reason why I would want to use  the [Ionic native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/) api over accessing Googles api directly?

Thanks

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.6",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/meteor": "^1.3.31",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.7.36",
    "accounts-base-client-side": "^0.1.1",
    "accounts-phone": "0.0.1",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.18.0",
    "google-maps": "^3.2.1",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "meteor-client-side": "^1.3.5",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.4",
    "meteor-rxjs": "^0.4.5",
    "meteor-typings": "^1.3.1",
    "moment": "^2.15.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The other release candidates work with Googles api (noy just ionic-native)

I do have the following in my `index.html`

`<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXX"></script>`

and in my `pckage.json`

`"@types/googlemaps": "^3.25.40",`

(run `npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev`)

Added the following to `declarations.d.ts`

`/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts" />`